# Unable to decrypt and read encrypted image file

Tags: java, image, aes

Here is my simple image encryption class, in which I am:

1. Reading a image from one place into bytes
2. Encrypting those bytes
3. Again create image from these encrypted bytes

Code:

```
public class ImageEncrypt {

  Cipher cipher; 

  public static byte[] convertImageToByteArray(String sourcePath) {
    byte[] imageInByte = null;
    try{

      BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File(
      sourcePath));

      // convert BufferedImage to byte array
      ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      ImageIO.write(originalImage, "jpg", baos);
      baos.flush();
      imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
      baos.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return imageInByte;
  }

  public static void convertByteArrayToImage(byte[] b , String path) {

    try{

      InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
      BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);

      ImageIO.write(bImageFromConvert, "jpg", new File(
      path));

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }


  public static void main(String args []){
    final String strPassword = "password12345678";

    SecretKeySpec initVector = new SecretKeySpec(strPassword.getBytes(), "AES");
    AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new IvParameterSpec(strPassword.getBytes()); 

    try{
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"); 

      cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, initVector, paramSpec); 

      byte[] ecrypted = cipher.doFinal(convertImageToByteArray("C:/Users/user/Desktop/a.jpg"));

      convertByteArrayToImage(ecrypted,"C:/Users/user/user/enc.jpg");

      System.out.println("converted to encrypted file .... ");
    }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Now I am getting problem in step three when I try to make image from encrypted bytes. It throws an exception given below:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromRenderedImage(ImageTypeSpecifier.java:925)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.getWriter(ImageIO.java:1591)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1520)
    at ImageEncrypt.convertByteArrayToImage(ImageEncrypt.java:55)
    at ImageEncrypt.main(ImageEncrypt.java:83)
```

I don't know where I am going wrong? I am doing the same to convert files (docs, pdf, etc.) to encrypt and it works fine (of course in that case I am using different stream classes for byte conversion) but I am unable to understand why it is messing up here?

Answer (score 2):

After you've encrypted the data, it's no longer a valid image file. Trying to use `ImageIO` on the encrypted data is like opening up the result of encrypting a text file in notepad, and expecting to see text.

To get an `Image`, you need to decrypt the data before you ask `ImageIO` to read it.

It's not at all clear what your `convertByteArrayToImage` method is really meant to do - if the aim is just to write the bytes to a file, why go via `Image` at all? Why not dump the bytes straight to disk? They're *already* the encrypted representation of an image - there's no need to try to interpret them as an image again. If you want to apply some sort of image transformation (e.g. *always* writing out a JPEG, even if the input is a PNG) then that should be done on the *unencrypted* data.

(Likewise on `convertImageToByteArray`, given that you're *starting* with a file on disk, there's no point in loading that as an image unless you want to perform an image-specific transformation.)

Side-notes:

- Don't use the overload of `String.getBytes()` which doesn't take a charset - it will use the platform default encoding, which means it's not portable across platforms
- You're converting the encrypted data to base64 as well, but then ignoring the result. Why?

Comment: base64 line is just mistakenly printed

Comment: `Why not dump the bytes straight to disk?` I am dumping them in the form of image.Please clear that what do you want to say? I am not getting it properly

Comment: @despicable: By the time it hits disk, *it's just bytes*. It's not like the file "knows" it's an image, just because it was written by `ImageIO`. To put it another way: encryption doesn't care about the nature of the data. You can encrypt a file without knowing anything about how the data would normally be interpreted: load the bytes, encrypt them, save the result. There's no need for `ImageIO` at all here.

Comment: so what I need to change in my code? As well as is it achievable to store it as an encrypted image file (using AES) at the end by this?